# roofing shingles and underlayment

Tags: roofing, shingles

Can we revisit GAF Timberline vs OC Duration Trudefinition shingles?  I've seen that in years past, both companies have had problems with their products.  Is this still true?  Is one now better than the other? Is 30# felt better than Deck Defense Underlayment (OC)?

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off-topic. See the help pages for info.

Answer (score 1):

I will forever be a fan of the 'new' sythetic underlayments versus the asphault-based underlayments. In the life of roofing shingles, synthetic will last as long (maybe not 100+ years as asphault will, but just as long as the shingles will anyway), much easier to install, and much more durable.

As far as GAF vs, Owens Corning products, they are both home center brands. Home center brands of products are produced at home center dictated pricing, and some shortcuts may be made to meet that price. Either is a decent brand, and will suit their purpose, just don't expect to call in a warranty 20 years from now. In roofing, you get what you pay for.

Comment: Ahhhh yes, the "Home Center" variant... what a wonderful thing! So ... CHEAP. Indeed, you get what you pay for. Not quite the same issue, but I had a 20 year flooring tile, that 2.5 years after installation had a problem with 2, and "zippo" the company no longer existed. Thanks Orange. (It was an Orange special).